# Sidekiq has busy processes and they never go away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm using the latest version of Sidekiq (2.15.2). I'm not sure how this happened but for some reason, my Sidekiq dashboard always has 2 busy processes.

[image]

When I click on busy, I just get the message, "Internal Server Error."

I tried stopping and restarting Sidekiq, but I still get the 2 busy processes. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Here is my log after resetting Sidekiq.

```
2013-11-13T05:09:02Z 2508 TID-osg9yldog INFO: Received USR1, no longer accepting new work
2013-11-13T05:09:02Z 2508 TID-osgbbuwe4 INFO: Shutting down 25 quiet workers
2013-11-13T05:09:04Z 2593 TID-ow9gk2yd0 INFO: Received USR1, no longer accepting new work
2013-11-13T05:09:04Z 2593 TID-ow9hyfa04 INFO: Shutting down 25 quiet workers
2013-11-13T05:09:32Z 2508 TID-osg9yldog INFO: Shutting down
2013-11-13T05:09:32Z 2508 TID-osgbbuwe4 INFO: Shutting down 0 quiet workers
2013-11-13T05:09:36Z 2593 TID-ow9gk2yd0 INFO: Shutting down
2013-11-13T05:09:36Z 2593 TID-ow9hyfa04 INFO: Shutting down 0 quiet workers
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15613 TID-osg19rhj4 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.15.2 using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options {}
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15613 TID-osg19rhj4 INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15613 TID-osg19rhj4 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15613 TID-osg19rhj4 INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15698 TID-ox8r4hzlg INFO: Booting Sidekiq 2.15.2 using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options {}
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15698 TID-ox8r4hzlg INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15698 TID-ox8r4hzlg INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2013-11-13T05:10:33Z 15698 TID-ox8r4hzlg INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: Can you stop sidekiq, clear the log, start it and then update your question with your log?

Comment: Try to flush redis db, run ```redis-cli``` and do ```flushdb```

Comment: I tried that, but that also removed all my history and statistics (processed count, failed count, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a default `redis.conf` you'll find the following lines:

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir ./
```

This means Redis will write on those periods a snapshot of the current status.

When you are developing probably you'd like to delete this file or commenting all the `save` lines as per `redis.conf` document before restarting the server again, or it will try to pick up any previous activity.